RDP/Thony: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!
I am using RDP acces to Raspberry 4 Pi and Thonny to run simple code (user rdp):
    import board
    import neopixel
    
    # NeoPixels must be connected to D10, D12, D18 or D21 to work.
    
    num_pixels = 10
    ORDER = neopixel.GRB
    
    pixels1 = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D21, num_pixels, brightness = 0.2, auto_write = False, pixel_order = ORDER)
    
    pixels1[0] = (255, 0, 0)
    pixels1.show()

After running in Thonny I get error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/home/rdp/Desktop/test_led.py", line 9, in <module>
     pixels1 = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D10, num_pixels, brightness = 0.2, auto_write = False, pixel_order = ORDER)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/neopixel.py", line 141, in
 __init__
     self.pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(pin)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/digitalio.py", line 193, in
 __init__
     self.direction = Direction.INPUT   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/digitalio.py", line 223, in
 direction
     self._pin.init(mode=Pin.IN)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/bcm283x/pin.py",
 line 40, in init
     GPIO.setup(self.id, GPIO.IN) RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!

I added user rdp to kmem and gpio groups, restart system:
admin@raspberrypi:~ $ groups rdp 
rdp : sudo root kmem gpio

But eror not gone:
rdp@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ cat /dev/mem
cat: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted

If I use sudo for rdp all working fine.
Help me please, whats wrong? How allow user rdp run scripts without sudo?
Tnx
